# Need to install VMware vSphere on My Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

I need to install VMware VSphere on My Ubuntu 16.04. Is this possible to install in my desktop. How do i do it?

Is it possible to install it on VMPlayer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. We need to install VMPlayer on ubunutu Desktop. Then we are going to install VMware ESxi on top of it.

[VMware ESxi Server Installation Guide](https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=free-esxi6#2011162514001)